# Text over image on hover using instagram plugin

Tags: html, css, instafeedjs

I finally got this pretty close, but I"m using Instafeed.js and my 4 images are perfectly centered horizonatally but my hover action that has a color overlay with text is off to the left.

Not sure what's up with this, but flexbox should center all this?

here's the code

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#instafeed {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery-item img {
  position: absolute;
}

.caption_layer {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

.caption_layer:hover {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  background: rgba(169,189,80,0.9);
  opacity: 1;
}

.instaCaption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:#5D5855;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="instafeed"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '',
    clientId: '',
    accessToken: '',
    template: '<a class="gallery-item" target="_blank" href="{{link}}"><img class="image_img" src="{{image}}" /><div class="caption_layer"><p class="instaCaption">{{model.likes.count}} Likes</p></div></a>',
    useHttp: true
    });
  feed.run();
});

</body>
```

What's the best way to get the hover to work, while keeping all images centered in a horizontal row and making sure the overlay is always the size of the image?